# Почему не отрабатывает контроллер (Yii1.1.17)?

Tags: php, yii, mvc, controller

Собственно проблема в следующем, почитал документацию, что-то более менее понял, решил создать контроллер, чтобы отобразить Hello World! 
Посмотрел на структуру того, что уже было, а был дефолтный простейший сайт с несколькими страницами где страница с контактно формой, например, располагается тут: *//site.ru/index.php?r=site/contact*
т.е Контроллер **SiteController.php** содержит метод действия **actionContact**  который успешно рендерит **представление** **contact.php** из папки **views/site/**
Теперь я решил повторить концепцию:

1. Создал свой контроллер в папке с контроллерами **protected/controllers/PanelController.php**.
   код:

`class PanelController extends CController{
 public function actionMain(){
   $this->render('main');
 }
}`

2. Создал файл представления здесь **views/panel/main.php** где просто написал "привет мир";
3. Обратился по адресу *//site/index.php?r=panel/main*

Но ожидаемого результата я не получил.
Никак не могу понять, что я упустил, почему дефолтный сайт работает и все экшны там отрабатывают, а мой вариант не работает. Конфигурация UrlManager не задана, по идее ведь он должен понимать по умолчанию такой запрос *//site/index.php?r=panel/main*
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

P.s
Я также пробовал наследовать от Controller а не от CController, хотя в документации именно CController.
И да, ошибка следующая [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забыл написать про ошибку, обычную выдает:
CHttpException
Unable to resolve the request "panel/main".

ССontroller тк в документации приводятся такие примеры http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/basics.controller
return не пробовал секунду

Comment: я вот сейчас смотрю экшны которые в стандартных контроллерах, там нет return и всё работает. И да, там наследование от Controller хотя я и так и так пробовал

Comment: Вы определитесь для начала какую версию фреймворка вы используете... Ибо ссылка идет на пример `yii1`, а вы видимо делаете что-то на `yii2`. Логично, что ничего не работает....А может и 1 версию используете...из меток непонятно.... Вы попробуйте для начала перекопировать `SiteController` и `actionContact` на `actionMain` и изменить `Site` на `Panel` и посмотрите будет что-то работать или нет....... А то непонятный гибрид вы пытаетесь соорудить и мы тут запутаны а что конкретно вы используете.

Comment: `return` во 2 фреймворке используется.... просто ваши метки и заголовок первоначальный изначально запутали.

Comment: У меня в принципе возникает эта проблема, на любой версии. 
Я пробовал скопировать контроллер,  ошибка остается. Скажите, yii точно автоматически обрабатывает запросы и подгружает классы контроллеров или ей нужно указывать на эти классы и соответствие с полученным контроллером в запросе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37244/discussion-between-alexandr-karpulix-and--).

Comment: Если не сложно, покажите еще роуты из конфига? Как они определены? Не переопределяли?

Comment: Вы о настройках UrlManager?

Answer (score 1):

Вышло очень курьезно. Сидел через консоль используя mcedit для правки, не привык еще к нему достаточно хорошо, он подсвечивает синтаксис php даже когда нет открывающего тега php, я провозился уйму времени, не обратив внимания на то, что не поставил открывающего тега.